# Bootstrap Carousel not working with different JQuery and Bootsrap files order

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had an issue with Bootstrap carousel working locally in my dev environment, but not working when moved to an external server. I was told to change the order of the files in the HTML file so JQuery would be after Bootstrap:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="modernizr-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

This sometimes work ans shows the carousel, but then the carousel doesn't move and the console says: "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery". I saw people suggesting to switch the files order again in order to solve the issue (which clearly brings me back to the first issue).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Call Jquery before bootstrap

Order should be

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This worked plus changing `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">` - the console gave an error about it.
Thanks!